# Creating MapKit JS with origin, destination and waypoints

Tags: javascript, mapkit

I'm migrating from Google Maps API to Apple MapKit JS for the simple reason I have a developer account with them and they offer more free hits.

Anyway, actual examples of MapKit JS are a bit thin (or at least Google isn't finding them - draw what conspiracy theories you will), so although I've got the basics going of displaying an embeded map, I can't seem to do the next step which is route between two points (Apple's documentation also seems impenetrable as they don't show examples).

Here's my script for a basic map:

```
<script>
    mapkit.init({
        authorizationCallback: function(done) {
        done('[MY-TOKEN]');
        }
    });

    var MarkerAnnotation = mapkit.MarkerAnnotation
    var myMarker = new mapkit.Coordinate(55.9496320, -3.1866360)
    var myRegion = new mapkit.CoordinateRegion(
        new mapkit.Coordinate(55.9496320, -3.1866360),
        new mapkit.CoordinateSpan(0.003, 0.003)
    );
    var map = new mapkit.Map("map");    
    var myAnnotation = new MarkerAnnotation(myMarker, { color: "#9b6bcc", title: "theSpace On The Mile"});
    map.showItems([myAnnotation]);  
    map.region = myRegion;
</script>
```

Now I want to:

• Show a walking route between two points

• Include waypoints on the route

Could someone show the code that would achieve this? Once I can see an example I know I'll get it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a solution to this so sharing it here for the benefit of others.

Let's start by saying Apple's MapKit JS doesn't appear to have a waypoints option as offered by Google Maps API - so the way around that is to create a map that stores the markers in an array and then routes from one to the next. The code stores the location of the last waypoint in a variable, and doesn't bother to draw a route to the last waypoint if this is the first one in the array (obviously).

```
<script>
    // Initiallise MapKit - you'll need your own long-lived token for this 
    mapkit.init({
        authorizationCallback: function(done) {
        done('[MY-TOKEN]');
        }
    });

    // Function to draw the route once MapKit has returned a response
    function directionHandler(error, data) {
        data["routes"].forEach(function(route, routeIdx) {
            if (routeIdx !== 0) { return; }
            overlays = [];
            route['path'].forEach(function(path) {
                // This styles the line drawn on the map
                let overlayStyle = new mapkit.Style({
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    strokeColor: "#9b6bcc"
                });
                let overlay = new mapkit.PolylineOverlay(path, {
                    style: overlayStyle
                });
                overlays.push(overlay);
            });
            map.addOverlays(overlays);
        });
    }

    // This asks MapKit for directions and when it gets a response sends it to directionHandler
    function computeDirections(origin,destination) {
        let directionsOptions = { 
            origin: origin, 
            destination: destination, 
            transportType: mapkit.Directions.Transport.Walking 
        };
        directions.route(directionsOptions, directionHandler);
    }   

    // This sets the initial region, but is overridden when all points have been potted to automatically set the bounds
    var myRegion = new mapkit.CoordinateRegion(
        new mapkit.Coordinate(55.9496320, -3.1866360),
        new mapkit.CoordinateSpan(0.05, 0.05)
    );

    var map = new mapkit.Map("map");
    map.region = myRegion;


    var myAnnotations = [];
    // lastWaypoint variable is 'unset' initially so the map doesn't try and find a route to the lastWaypoint for the first point of the route
    var lastWaypoint = "unset";
    var directions = new mapkit.Directions();

    // Array of co-ordinates and label for marker
    waypoints = [
        {name:'Sofi’s Bar',lat:55.9746308,lon:-3.1722282},
        {name:'TThe Roseleaf Cafe',lat:55.975992,lon:-3.173474},
        {name:'Hemingway’s',lat:55.9763631,lon:-3.1706564},
        {name:'Teuchter’s Landing',lat:55.9774693,lon:-3.1713826},
        {name:'The King’s Wark',lat:55.9761425,lon:-3.1695419},
        {name:'Malt and Hops',lat:55.975885,lon:-3.1698957},
        {name:'The Carrier’s Quarters',lat:55.9760813,lon:-3.1685323},
        {name:'Noble’s',lat:55.974905,lon:-3.16714},
        {name:'The Fly Half',lat:55.9747906,lon:-3.1674496},
        {name:'Port O’ Leith',lat:55.974596,lon:-3.167525}
    ];  

    // Loop through the array and create marker for each    
    waypoints.forEach(function(data) {
        var myAnnotation = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(new mapkit.Coordinate(data['lat'],data['lon']), { 
            color: "#9b6bcc", 
            title: data['name']
        });
        myAnnotations.push(myAnnotation);
        // As long as this isn't the first point on the route, draw a route back to the last point
        if(lastWaypoint!="unset") {
            computeDirections(lastWaypoint,new mapkit.Coordinate(data['lat'],data['lon']));
        }
        lastWaypoint = new mapkit.Coordinate(data['lat'],data['lon']);
    });
    map.showItems(myAnnotations);       
</script>
```

This map is for a pub crawl around Leith, so the trasportType is 'Walking', but change that to 'Automobile' if you so wish.

With credit to Vasile whose MapKit JS Demo (https://github.com/vasile/mapkit-js-demo) helped me understand a lot more about the options.